# Error when generating Apple Pass (nodejs) with @walletpass/pass-js

Tags: node.js, passbook, passkit

When trying to generate my Apple Pass using @walletpass/pass-js package, I'm getting `Bag Attributes SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. I have created the right `.p12` certificate for the designated `passType` and converted to `.pem` as stated in the documentation.

My controller for generating Apple Pass:

```
var Shopper = require("../models/shopper");
const { Template } = require("@walletpass/pass-js");
const { toHTTPError } = require("../util/utils");
const { s3AppleCertificatePassword } = require("../services/config");

class ApplePassController {
      async getById(req, res) {
        //  Functions regarding user accounts
        let accountId = req.query.accountId;
        ....
    
        // Create the template manually
        const template = new Template("storeCard", {
          passTypeIdentifier: "pass.com.identifier",
          teamIdentifier: "TEAMIDENTIFIER",
          organizationName: "ORGANIZATIONNAME",
          logoText: "LOGOTEXT",
        });
    
        // Find the certificate
        let pemEncodedPassCertificate = require("../services/applePass/Certificates.pem");
        template.setCertificate(pemEncodedPassCertificate);
        template.setPrivateKey(s3AppleCertificatePassword);
    
        // Setting the images
        await template.images.add("logo", "../image/applePass/logo.png", "1x");
        await template.images.add("icon", "../image/applePass/icon.png", "1x");
        await template.images.add("icon", "../image/applePass/icon@2x.png", "2x");
        await template.images.add("strip", "../image/applePass/strip.png", "1x");
        await template.images.add("strip", "../image/applePass/strip@2x.png", "2x");
    
        // Create a new pass from a template
        const pass = template.createPass({
          serialNumber: "SERIALNUMBER",
          description: "DESCRIPTION"
        });
    
        // Add the required fields to the pass
        pass.headerFields.add({ key: "key", label: "label", value: value });
        pass.secondaryFields.add({ key: "key", label: "label", value: value });
        pass.secondaryFields.add({ key: "key", label: "label", value: value });
    
        // To generate the file
        const buf = await pass.asBuffer();
        await fs.writeline("pkpass", buf);
    
        // Send the buffer directly to an HTTP server response
        return res.status(200).body(await pass.asBuffer());
      }
    }
    const applePassController = new ApplePassController();
    module.exports = applePassController;
```

The error:

```
(node:38515) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /Users/path/to/services/applePass/Certificates.pem:1
Bag Attributes
    ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
```

Thanks for the help!